# Implementing an Obj-C class in my Swift project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I'm trying to add a webshop to my app. The problem is that the webshop has provided me with an Obj-C framework and I'm only familiar with making iOS apps in Swift.

I've managed to setup an Obj-C bridging header and instantiate the webshop object.

My project looks like this:

[image]

When the shop button on my CodeDetailViewController gets tapped this function gets triggered:

```
@IBAction func shopButtonPressed(sender: UIButton){
    let instanceOfShop : Shop = Shop()
    instanceOfShop.showShop()
}
```

My Shop.m looks like this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <FMShop/FMShop.h>
#import "Shop.h"

@implementation Shop

- (void) showShop {
    //SANDBOX
    FMShop* shop = [[FMShop alloc] initWithKey:@"4M7HDPAQMY68S"
                                      storeKey:@"C8RSHBH710GK8"
                                       buyerID:nil
                                       sandbox:YES
                                    controller:nil
                                      delegate:nil];

    [shop showStore:kShopViewHome ID:nil];
}

@end
```

The showShop function in this class gets triggered. Nothing however shows up.

The manual on how to implement this webshop is aimed at Obj-C apps. Concerning the delegate it states:

*delegate: Please define a class or an interface that implements the delegates. Without such, the Store will not show. Please go to FMShopDelegate to see the supported list of methods and callbacks.*

This is what I could find in the framework:

```
@protocol FMShopDelegate <NSObject>
@optional

-(void)shopWillAppear:(FMShop*)shop;
-(void)shopDidAppear:(FMShop*)shop;
-(void)shopWillDisappear:(FMShop*)shop;
-(void)shopDidDisappear:(FMShop*)shop;
-(void)shopProductInfo:(FMShop*)shop products:(NSArray*)productArray;
-(void)shopHistoryOrderInfo:(FMShop*)shop orders:(NSArray*)orderArray;
-(void)shopPlaceOrderSuccess:(FMShop*)shop orderID:(NSString*)orderID;
-(void)shopOrderUserCancelled:(FMShop*)shop orderID:(NSString*)orderID;
-(void)shopFailed:(FMShop*)shop error:(FMShopErrorType)error;

@end
```

Can anyone tell me how to connect this final method to the right delegate?

Comment: You have to use bridge header  for accessing `obj-c` file in `swift`.

Comment: Already using a bridging header, how do I pass a delegate to the Obj-C file that is being used?

Comment: So you didn't get swift file instead of obj-c?

Comment: You conform FMShopDelegate protocol in your Shop class. Try implementing the delegate method to check if you get failure delegate method shopFailed:error: invoked.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like if you don't provide a delegate when you instantiate your instance of FMShop, then the show method will not work. In your Shop.m file, you're instantiating the FMShop object with `nil` as the delegate parameter.

Try having an object conform to the `FMShopDelegate` protocol, and passing this object as the delegate parameter. You could even have your Shop object conform to the protocol itself, and pass `self` as the delegate if that would serve your purposes.

You could do this in Swift in a new Shop.swift file, or in the Shop.m file in Objective-C:

Swift:

```
class Shop: NSObject {
    func showShop() {
        // I'm guessing on the syntax here, Xcode will help autocomplete the correct functions
        let shop = FMShop(key: KEY, storeKey: STOREKEY...)

        shop.show(store: kShopViewHome, id: nil)
    }
}

extension Shop: FMShopDelegate {
    // Implement any of the protocol functions you want here
}
```

Objective-C:

```
@interface Shop() <FMShopDelegate> // Conform to the delegate here
@end

@implementation Shop

- (void) showShop {
    //SANDBOX
    FMShop* shop = [[FMShop alloc] initWithKey:@"4M7HDPAQMY68S"
                                      storeKey:@"C8RSHBH710GK8"
                                       buyerID:nil
                                       sandbox:YES
                                    controller:nil
                                      delegate:self];

    [shop showStore:kShopViewHome ID:nil];
}

// Implement any of the protocol methods here

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use bridging header for accessing `obj-c` file in `swift`

Below is the apple doc to describe how to create & use bridging header

[Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use bridging header in your project.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html